# C# serial port problems with Arduino Rev 4 WIFI

Tags: c#, arduino, serial-port, serial-communication

I have problems using Arduino Rev 4 WIFI serial communcation with C#. When using an ardunio uno it works perfectly fine, and its with the same scripts on both the arduinos and the C# program.

I think there is a problem with my C# serial class.
What properties should I change/use?
Is there anyone else that have the same problem?

I am using following SerialPort class properties:

```
SerialPort class

Port = "COM3",
BaudRate = 9600,
DataBits = 8,
StopBits = StopBits.One,
ReadTimeOut = 10000,
WriteTimeOut = 10000,
DtrEnable = true,
RstEnable = true
```

Changing DtrEnable & RstEnable doesn't seem to change anyting